# Is it possible to embed javascript code into email body?

Tags: javascript, html, email

Now I am working on Laravel 5.8 project and I need to send email to admin after user registration.
Admin can see new email which says new user's registration and when he click "Approve" button on email, ajax url request should be run using javascript.
Of course, if I use `<a>` tag instead of `<button>`, I can make new url click event.
But I don't want an admin to see anything when he clicks "Approve".

I just want to know if I can embed javascript code into email body..

Thanks.

Comment: Email user agents don't run JavaScript code.

Comment: So do I have to use a tag like <a href="https://example.com/.../approve?_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">Approve</a>?

Comment: Yes, that should work, though in the world of email agents there's lots of variation. There are no solid standards comparable to what browsers do with HTML etc.